# How do I brute-force a password when I know the format?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

The format is 1 letter + 5 numbers (e.g. A12345).
Any method and software?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add that information. Note that product recomendations are off topic, but asking about methods is fine!

Comment: Use intruder,intercept the request,and brute force it.

Comment: You used the word "crack", which confused everyone. You are trying to "brute force" a password. I made the edit.

Comment: so you understand what is hack? because you question told me something different , so if you want to know the password example if the password is :A16462 its cool there are different way discover/find out the password , first is engineer social o using a keylogger this is the simple way but if you want to attack a server , take easy this is iligeal CIA / FBI gocha , but if you want to do this action you can use :https://github.com/topics/bruteforce there are a lot tools free for you but you should most understand the code of this script or you are a Script kiddie

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of passwords matching the format you want using `hashcat`:

```
hashcat --stdout -a 3 ?u?d?d?d?d?dhd
```

will generate Udddddhd where U is upper, d is digit, but the last 'hd' is just 'hd'.  More information about `hashcat` mask mode is [here](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack).

Once you've generated your wordlist, you can use a tool like [Hydra](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) or [Hatch](https://github.com/nsgodshall/Hatch) to feed those passwords into the web form.

Comment: @user238169 we are not going to walk you through installation and troubleshooting. We are not tech support. We can give you the methods that will work. And it is concerning that you are willing to pay someone else to crack an account for you.

Comment: or Enginner social

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `crunch`

To generate the output first with the following command options:

```
crunch 6 6 -t ,%%%%% -o 6chars.txt
```

Then you can feed that `6chars.txt` output to your software you are trying to brute force.